# Jquery last click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i can determine the last clicked id ?!
Because if i use :

```
 if(clicks > 1){
     var lc = event.target.id;  // Last Clicked event

     }
```

It will return the current button clicked id
I have something like this :

```
$('#menu).click(function(event) {

  clicks++;
   if(clicks > 1){
     var lc = event.target.id;  // Last Clicked event

     }
   console.log(lc);
```

And i have 2 buttons 
Now if i click on first button console log will show undefinded but if i click on second button it will show his id.I want to prevent that

Comment: Save it to a variable when the previous event happens.

Comment: This is very little information, but usually what you are doing is saving the previous event since there is no history of events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.data()` for this,

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li id="menu1">1</li>
   <li id="menu2">2</li>
   <li id="menu3">3</li>
   <li id="menu4">4</li>
   <li id="menu5">5</li>
</ul>​
```

---

```
$(".menu li").click(function() {
    if($(this).parent().data("lastClicked")){
        alert($(this).parent().data("lastClicked"));
    }
    $(this).parent().data("lastClicked", this.id);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aDUdq/

Comment: why noy using a *much simpler* local variable ??

Answer (score 1):

The variable `lc` is local. You must write instead :

```
var lc;
if(clicks > 1){
 lc = event.target.id;  // Last Clicked event
 }
console.log(lc);
```